# Sencha Touch: Clear listeners on an individual list item

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In a TreeStore I have a list item / record which differs from all the other records. I want to execute `window.open()` whenever the user clicks on this specific record. The other records should maintain their usual functionality. (`leafItemTap` => `detailCard`)

I have tried all events of NestedList that made sense to me but no success.

My basic idea is to clear all listeners on the list item and add a custom one for the `window.open()` task.

Comment: Have you tried to listen itemtap event and in the handler execute required logic? http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-event-itemtap

Comment: Yes, that was my first thought too. It will fire and execute the logic in the handler. But there's no way to prevent the detail card from popping up. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use select event, it's preventable so you just need to return false. However, you need to do extra work to deselect previously selected item:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-event-select